# custom message fails to build; no such file or directory

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, std-msgs, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the custom message documentation to the letter, and searched all the related questions on here, and unfortunately I am still stuck. Could you please have a look?

I am getting the same error building in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, both running Kinetic.

All my packages that have custom messages fail to build (`catkin_make` exits with error). The custom message definition are part of the package, and are not from another package. The error reason is the same for all the packages with custom messages (from my limited understanding the .msg file is not found for some reason):   `fatal error: ... : No such file or directory ... >`
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

The package organization follows the documentation:
[image: image description]

where the custom message file is called my_msg.msg and is inside the msg directory. The contents of `my_msg.msg` are not suspect either:

```
int32 my_int
float64 my_float
```

The package.xml does contain the needed lines:

```
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

The CMakeLists.txt contains everything the documentation mentions, and I even ran `catkin_create_pkg test` to make sure all the items are arranged in the correct order. Here is the file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(g_custom_messages)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
    roscpp 
    rospy
    std_msgs 
    message_generation
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  my_msg.msg
)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs )

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(custom_msg_subscriber src/custom_msg_subscriber.cpp)

target_link_libraries(custom_msg_subscriber ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

and in the source code (file name is `custom_msg_subscriber.cpp` and it is inside the src directory), I am refrencing the custom message as `#include <g_custom_messages/my_msg.h>`, and am accessing the data via:

```
void poseMessageReceived(const g_custom_messages::my_msg &msg) 
{
    storeInt = msg.my_int;
    storeFloat = msg.my_float;
}
```

All the web search gymnastics I did have not helped. Could you please let me know why am I getting an error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306884/custom-message-fails-to-build;-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2018-10-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-27**:
Please check the [catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html) on how to do this.

I'm fairly certain you're missing the `add_dependencies(..)` bit to let CMake know that `custom_msg_subscriber` depends on the msgs having been generated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-27**:
Additionally: for the future: please don't post screenshots of terminals. It's all text, so you can just copy-paste it into your question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-27**:
And for reference: updating the `CMakeLists.txt` of nodes *using* your custom message is explained in the [next tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes-1).

**Comment by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on 2018-10-27**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you very much for helping. I am learning ROS on my own and I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-28**:
No problem. Good to hear you got things to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gvdhoorn was absolutely right. Thank you.

If you follow the msg and srv tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv), which is what I did, the only mention of `add_dependencies(...)` is in a link at the end of section 5... which I must have missed. When looking over the next tutorial (as gvhoorn pointed out. see: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29 ), you can see how `add_dependencies(source_file_name package_name_generate_messages_cpp)` is used to build projects with custom message.

adding `add_dependencied(...)` to all the CMakeLists.txt in the packages with custom messges fixed my catkin build problems.

---

Originally posted by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) with karma: 247 on 2018-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50314/adde/) on 2020-03-25**:
Hi, I hade the same problem and when I added the 'add_dependencied' some compilation errors were fixed.
But one type of error remains, it seems that the namespace declared in the generated h (msg_name.h) does not exist. The scenario I have is the following:

```
in file foo.h
    \#include "msg_name.h"
    ...
    namespace_in_h_file::msg_name foo;
    ...
```

This compiles 9 times of 10 with catkin build and the error is that namespace_in_h_file is not a type.
Any tips on how to proceed?

**Comment by [Cullen SUN](https://answers.ros.org/users/113591/cullen-sun/) on 2022-08-15**:
yes, this do fix my problem. My code can change can be found here. https://github.com/CullenSUN/robotics_se_project_5/commit/762b370b5ac814a7309c5292615739a25a4ec57f